# Can the properties of the grid's cells in blessed-contrib be changed?

Tags: node.js, command-line, text-based, tui

I am experimenting with `blessed` in Node and naturally I found `blessed-contrib`, now, I want to create a layout with rows of different heights but even though I can control the height/width of the elements inside the grid cells, I don't seem to be able to change the height/width of the cells.

Is it possible to control cell's properties or should I just look a different design on my app layout to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible starting blessed-contrib@1.0.9:

```
grid.set(row, col, rowSpan, colSpan, obj, opts)
```